# Add React provider function to a global window object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am wonder if it is a good practice to put function in `window` variable.

For Example:

## App.js

```
  ...
  <PageContextProvider>
    <AuthContextProvider>
      <Content />
    </AuthContextProvider>
  </PageContextProvider>
  ...
```

In `App.js` I am wrapping Context Providers to a `Content`

## PageContextProvider.js

```
/**
  * Display Snackbar Messages On Page
  * @param {string} message Message title to be displayed
  * @param {string} status Message Status
  * @param {objext} options Other Options
  * @returns {void}
  */
const addMessage = (message, status = 'success', options = {}) => {
  const m = {
    message,
    status,
    ...options
  };

  setMessages({ ...messages, [new Date().getTime()]: m });
};

/**
  * Display Snackbar Messages On Page
  * @param {string} message Message title to be displayed
  * @param {string} status Message Status
  * @param {objext} options Other Options
  * @returns {void}
  */
const removeMessage = messagekey => {
  const m = messages;
  delete m[messagekey];
  setMessages({ ...m });
};


useEffect(() => {
  window.addMessage = addMessage;
  window.removeMessage = removeMessage;
}, []);
```

As you can see I added `addMessage` and `removeMessage` in `window` object.
This is how I am going to use it:

## AuthContextProvider.js

```
...
  const login = async (email, password) => {
    setAuth(true);
    window.addMessage('You Are successfully Logged In', 'success');
  };
...
```

Or anywhere in my app:

## ExampleComponent.js

```
...
  window.addMessage('This is example warning message from ExampleComponent', 'warning');
...
```

Of course I can pass `addMessage` and `removeMessage` in value of Content Provider but I prefer doing this way because I need to write less code
I know that using `window` variable is not good and it is slow but these are only snack messages probably used once per minute or two

I want to know if it is good practice and should I do this in production.
Thank you

Comment: this is not a good idea if your going to "server render" which doesnt have window and you might encouter bugs with diff devices and browsers

Comment: I am never going to do ssr in this app

Comment: React.Context or Redux are the more conventional tools for this.

Comment: @jmargolisvt If you read my question again you will see that I am already using React.Context